# Google chart javascript

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm using Google Charts for a small projects for myself, and I'm not very good with javascript so I thought I'd ask for some help.

Basically I want to change the current values of the chart by pressing a button.
This is the script:

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
['', 'YES', 'NO'],
['',  5,      2],
]);

var options = {
title: 'Win / Loss ratio',
vAxis: {title: 'Chart',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
};

var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

The values 5 and 2 should be changed when clicking button_1 or button_2
All help is appreciated.

Comment: How do you want the values to change?  Is the user entering a new number?  Should the numbers increment?  Something else?

Comment: @asgallant the numbers should increment when pressing either button. Ex: Button_1 increases YES value and Button_2 the NO value. Sorry for being unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['', 'YES', 'NO'],
        ['',  5,      2],
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'Win / Loss ratio',
        vAxis: {title: 'Chart',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);

    function incrementYes () {
        data.setValue(0, 1, data.getValue(0, 1) + 1);
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    function incrementNo () {
        data.setValue(0, 2, data.getValue(0, 2) + 1);
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    // assumes button_1 and button_2 have id's "button_1" and "button_2"
    var btn1 = document.querySelector('#button_1');
    var btn2 = document.querySelector('#button_2');

    if (document.addEventListener) {
        // add event listener in most browsers
        btn1.addEventListener('click', incrementYes);
        btn2.addEventListener('click', incrementNo);
    }
    else if (document.attachEvent) {
        // add event listener in IE
        btn1.attachEvent('onclick', incrementYes);
        btn2.attachEvent('onclick', incrementNo);
    }
    else {
        // add event listener in legacy browsers
        btn1.onclick = incrementYes;
        btn2.onclick = incrementNo;
    }
}
```

Comment: you wrote btn1 and bt1, are those supposed to be different ? also I'm wondering if the #button_1 and #button_2 are div's or form buttons ? thanks

Comment: Sorry, the buttons should be `btn1` and `btn2` - I'll fix it in my code above.  Also, it actually doesn't matter what element the buttons are, as long as it will throw a "click" event (and off the top of my head, I can't think of any HTML elements that won't throw a click event).